# Traveling on WestBahn with unreserved seats

Tags: trains, austria

I am traveling to Salzburg (Salzburg Hbf) from Vienna (Wien Westbahnhof) on the WestBahn train booked on [thetrainline.com](https://thetrainline.com). While booking, I did not select "reserve seats" option. According to their FAQs, with such tickets, I can sit on any vacant seat (which is not first class).

In such case, when I am looking for a seat, how will I know if that seat is not reserved by any other person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something has changed recently, they at least used to have small displays on the luggage rack above each seat, telling you if the seats are reserved or not.

You can find several pictures of the interior of a WESTbahn train [here, a bit down the page](http://www.styria-mobile.at/home/forum/index.php/topic,6247.90.html), where you can see the small, black display boxes.

Comment: Even when trains usually have the markers, they do not always work and when they do they may not be right in last minute made reservations. In which case you can go with Daniils answer.

Comment: @Willeke WESTbahn only sells seat reservations up to two hours before the train departs from the first station. There are no last-minute reservations to consider.

Comment: I can confirm this. I traveled today. I just wanted to add this info for future readers: If seat is reserved, on the luggage rack, station name will be written. It means that seat is reserved from that station.

Answer (score 0):

If the seat indicators don’t work as mentioned in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148627/89966), it might just be a case of arriving later when most people would’ve arrived/moving if the seat was already reserved.

Comment: Or just taking the risk and move on when the person who reserved the seat show up.

Comment: While this answer might not be correct in the normal run of things in these trains, I have been in many trains where the system did not work as it should have and this answer was the one that worked.

Comment: The train stops very frequently, usually every 10-20 minutes and on each stop, new passengers with seat reservations will embark. What exactly do you mean with 'arriving later' (than what)?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo arrive just before the departure time

Comment: Departure time of which of the 8 stations the train is departing from? My point is, there will be new passengers with seat reservations entering the train at every station the train stops. Finding a vacant seat in Vienna, does not mean that the seat is not reserved.